# Is there a keyboard shortcut for middle button click in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, shortcuts

Shift insert will paste what's in the clipboard, but the middle button click (paste selected text) doesn't seem to have a keyboard shortcut that I can find.
This is ubuntu. Anybody know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use need to install **xkbset** (you can use the Synaptic Package Manager). Then see this [blog post](http://linuxaleph.blogspot.com/2008/11/mapping-middle-click-to-keyboard-key.html) for the how-to.

Quoted from the blog post:

> First, we need install an old accessibility extension to X which is called **xkbset**. In Ubuntu or Debian, just `sudo apt-get install xkbset`.
>   The original idea of this software is to provide support for people
>   who might not be able to use a mouse or keyboard so well, so it
>   enables things like MouseKeys (control the cursor with the numpad) and
>   StickyKeys (hit shift, lift off, type a letter, get a capital), and
>   SlowKeys (only register a keypress after a certain amount of time).
>   But we're going to use it to map a keyboard key to a mouse button with
>   MouseKeys.
>
> First, we'll get rid of all the cursor-control stuff, so you can still
>   use your numpad. As root, edit the file
>   `/usr/share/X11/xkb/compat/mousekeys` and remove everything between
>   `interpret.repeat= False;` and `// New Keysym Actions`. Notice this maps
>   some new "keysym" actions below, specifically the one called
>   `Pointer_Button2`.
>
> Next, we'll make a script to configure xkbset, to turn MouseKeys on,
>   to not turn it off after a period of inactivity, and to map a key of
>   your choice to middle-click. Here's my `~/.middle-click.sh`:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # set XKB layout
> setxkbmap -layout us
> # turn on mousekeys
> xkbset m
> # stop mousekeys expiring after a timeout
> xkbset exp =m
> # map keysym to other keysym
> xmodmap -e "keysym Menu = Pointer_Button2"
> # this also works
> # xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = Pointer_Button2"
> ```
>
> This maps the Menu key (it's between Right Alt and Right Ctrl on my
>   keyboard, looks like a menu with a mouse cursor) to mouse button 2,
>   which is middle click. Notice I can also use any other key on the
>   keyboard, by commenting out the `keysym` line, and using the `keycode`
>   line. Keycodes are different from keyboard to keyboard, so to get the
>   keycode of the key you wish to use, run `xev` in a terminal, push the
>   key you desire, and watch the terminal output.
>
> For the Mac users, left-click is button 1, and right-click is button
>   3. If I was using a Mac, I imagine I'd map Right Command to Button2, and Right Option to Button3. I hope the right side of these buttons
>   has a different keycode to the left side. If not, I've read of people
>   using F11 and/or F12. `man xmodmap` will tell you how to use a modifier
>   like Cmd+F12 if you so desire.
>
> Under Gnome, I use System -> Preferences -> Sessions to start this
>   script as I log in, so I don't have to worry about it again. Don't
>   forget to make your script executable with `chmod +x ~/.middle-click.sh`

Answer (score 21):

Depending on the program try <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>.

Comment: U ROCK!!! This totally saved me after hours and hours of fruitless testing.  Dell notebook - 2018 - ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work at all in Firefox.