# Middle mouse button locking

Tags: linux, mouse

I use 3d graphics software that has you press middle mouse button to pan around. Pressing and holding the middle mouse button for longer periods of time unfortunately puts a lot a strain on my wrist.

I heard something about some feature where you can press a button and keep the middle mouse button down until you press it again.

I don't know if it's software programmable or it's available on some mice with dedicated button. If so what are some examples of mice that support this feature?

Comment: Do you want to make your middle mouse button 'sticky', or maybe shift that function to a foot pedal? Which distro do you use, and which version number? Some adaptive and assistive technology apps require a specific release, or a specific desktop. Please add this info to your question by clicking [edit]. Please do not click Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Use a keyboard shortcut to replace holding the mouse: https://superuser.com/questions/111017/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-middle-button-click-in-ubuntu

Comment: You might want to look into using autohotkey: https://www.autohotkey.com/ I'm not familiar enough to write a script for it, but maybe this comment will inspire someone else to answer with an ahk script that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing, switch to a Logitech M535 BlueTooth Mouse. It installs the Logitech software.

The middle button locks (one click) by default. Excellent mouse

Also (now at a Client) a Logitech M215 USB Mouse (and Keyboard) works the same way. Click the middle button to lock and pan around